# react-redux store data - reducer setter

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to store a dictionary in react-redux in react-native.

So my action looks like this :

```
let data = {};
export const setData = (pData) => ({
  type: 'SET',
  data: pData,//I don't know how to store the data in data declared in parent
});

export const getData = () => ({
  type: 'GET',
  data: data,
});
```

And my reducer looks like this :

```
const items = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET':
      return [
       //I don't know how to set the data here
      ];
    case 'GET':
      return state;
    default:
      return null;
  }
};

export default items;
```

I looked in many tutorial on YouTube, they just you need to paste this, and boom.

If I get cleared with one dictionary, I think I can work with others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part almost right. You don't need "GET" to get data and this part `let data = {}` should be in reducer;

```
export const setData = (pData) => ({
  type: 'SET',
  data: pData,
});
/*
export const getData = () => ({
  type: 'GET',
  data: data,
});
*/
```

Reducer

```
const initState = {
  data:[],
  anotherSate:[] 
}

const rootReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case 'SET': {
      return {
        ...state, // if you have more states
        data: [action.data, ...state.data]
      }
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default rootReducer;
```

You can get your "Data". "New" component

```
//Your component code
//...
this.props.data // here is your "data"
//...

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    data: state.data,
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(NewComponent);
```

In order to check if your `Reducer` works, try to add something in your `initState` and extract the data in NewComponent

Comment: `[Wed Aug 12 2020 13:48:15.901]  ERROR    Error: Invalid value of type object for mapStateToProps argument when connecting component Store.`

Comment: and I'm using `@react-navigation/stack`, `@react-navigation/native` all together

Comment: Did you try just get data or both?

Comment: I tried setting `function Store({dispatch, navigation}) {... dispatch(setData(items))....`

Comment: Try just add last part (New Component) to any your Component and do `console.log(this.props.data) `. Don't forget to add something into `const initState = {
  data:[{hello},{world}]}` and in the beginning of your component `import { connect } from 'react-redux';`

Comment: can you give me your paste, please ? my code looks like this : https://pastebin.com/ZRWf8LxR

Comment: add this component to your project: https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-dream-bfszn?file=/src/App.js

Comment: doesn't work here is the log : https://pastebin.com/hCetRBpq

Comment: Man it's difficult to say what wrong with your code without the whole picture. Probably something wrong with createStore or something else. I would recommend you to watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KcC8KZ_Ga2M

Comment: all it need is mapDispatchToProps... added this piece of code, now everything works fine... thanks...

Answer (score 0):

```
const items = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET':
      return {
        ...state, // adding the previous state first
        data: action.data // here data can be any keyword you want to save your dictionary in
      }
    case 'GET':
      return state;
    default:
      return null;
 }
 };
```